Личная эффективность, личностный рост и др. сочетания внутри этих пар слов
Безотносительно вашего личного отношения к этим, назовём их так, "вещам", почему в русском языке, по крайней мере в разговорном и в языке интернет-статей, используются, преимущественно, такие варианты:

личная эффективность (в англ.: personal productivity)
тренинги личностного роста

А вот "личностная эффективность" встречается ну очень редко. Про тренинги "личного роста" тоже не особо слышно. Как вообще правильно? И про эффективность, и про рост.

Раньше "тренинги личностного роста" были очень модными, сейчас не знаю, помогали они вроде так себе) может поэтому. Сейчас модно слово коучинг, и как мы тут выяснили оно от слова коуч-повозка и родственное с кучер, коучер - это тренер-наставник для кучеров, который обучал их управлению лошадьми.
